# None of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I am trying to use enhanced input components in Unreal 5.1 but I get this error:

> CryptRaiderCharacter.cpp(91): [C2665]
> ‘UEnhancedInputComponent::BindAction’: none of the 4 overloads could
> convert all the argument types

The line of the error:

```
void ACryptRaiderCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
  ...
  if (UEnhancedInputComponent* EnhancedInputComponent = CastChecked<UEnhancedInputComponent>(PlayerInputComponent))
    {
        EnhancedInputComponent->BindAction(MoveAction, ETriggerEvent::Triggered, this, &ACryptRaiderCharacter::Move);   // error here   
    }

}


void ACryptRaiderCharacter::Move(FInputActionValue& Value)
{
    const float DirectionValue = Value.Get<float>();
    if (Controller && DirectionValue != 0.f)
    {
        FVector Forward = GetActorForwardVector();
        AddMovementInput(Forward, DirectionValue);      
    }
}
```

Declarations

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category=Input)
UInputAction* MoveAction;

void Move(FInputActionValue& Value);
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Hard to say given the information given (plus my lack of knowledge of this API) but the declaration of `ACryptRaiderCharacter::Move` seems highly relevant. Please include that in your question.

Comment: Also I don't know if it makes any difference in this case, but you should specify which version of unreal engine you are using, and remove the tag for the other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution `Move` function need to be like this:

`void ACryptRaiderCharacter::Move(const FInputActionValue &Value)`

Comment: This was exactly what was wrong with mine. I forgot my const on both my header and my imp.